# Python: altering raw_input?

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a program to create a questionaiire, ultimately giving back info the user inputs. Here's my code:

> > .   Def questionaiire:

```
>>.   Loop = 0
>>
>>    While loop != 1:

>>      Print "A: name"

>>      Print "B: age"

>>      Print "B: Favorite color".

>>      Zen = raw_input("choose a, b, or c") #my problem line

>>      If zen == "a" or "A":

>>        A = raw_input("Input your name: ")

>>.     Elif zen == "b" or "B":

>>.       B = raw_input:("Input your age: ")

>>.     Elif zen == "C" or "c":

>>        C = raw_input("Input your favorite color")

>>      Else:

>>        Print A, B, C

>>        Break
```

The ending bit is a little more sophisticated, but essentially thats my function. Help?
I also tried inserting return after the if and elifs, but that made the program stuck(couldnt input) so i took them out

Comment: Please format the code exactly in the way you do it in your script. Otherwise if someone wants to help you, will first need to fix it for you.

Answer (score 7):

There are a number of syntax errors in your code.

- You must not capitalize `def`, `while`, `print`, `if`, `elif`, `else`, `break`, or any other [python keyword](http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#keywords), they *must* be all lower case.
- You need to be consistent in the casing of your variable names. `Zen` and `zen` are two different variables!
- You must put parenthesis after the name of the function, like this: `def questionaiire():`
- The period in this line is a syntax error. Remove it.

  ```
  print "B: Favorite color".
  ```
- The colon following `raw_input` in this line is a syntax error. Remove it.

  ```
  B = raw_input:("Input your age: ")
  ```
- I don't know what the `>>`s at the start of each line is, I presume it's not part of the actual source code. If it is, remove all occurances of `>` at the start of a line.
- This line does not do what you think it does:

  ```
  if zen == "a" or "A":
  ```

  It's interpreted like this:

  ```
  if (zen == "a") or "A":
  ```

  So it's always true, since `"A"` evaluates to `True`. Write it like this instead:

  ```
  if zen.lower() == "a":
  ```

Here's a working example. I've made as few changes as possible to the code, to ease comparison.

```
def questionaiire():
    a = b = c = ""
    while True:
        print "a: name"
        print "b: age"
        print "c: favorite color"
        zen = raw_input("choose a, b, or c: ")
        if zen.lower() == "a":
            a = raw_input("input your name: ")
        elif zen.lower() == "b":
            b = raw_input("input your age: ")
        elif zen.lower() == "c":
            c = raw_input("input your favorite color: ")
        else:
            print a, b, c
            break
```

You never used the `loop` variable, so I've removed it. Since you use `break`, there's no real need for it in this code example.

The number and variety of mistakes you've made writing this short code indicates that you would *really* benefit from reading through at least the first few chapters of the [python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/) before programming any more python or asking further python-related questions on this site.